# npm install cypress-downloadfile --save-dev gives error

Tags: plugins, cypress

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-downloadfile

Basically, I want to download a file using Cypress.

But when I am trying to install this plugin it is giving me the below error

```
'Log files:
/Users/myMacbook/.npm/_logs/2023-05-22T19_54_03_310Z-debug-0.log

# npm resolution error report

While resolving: eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
Found: eslint@8.41.0
node_modules/eslint
  peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || >=8.0.0" from @eslint-community/eslint-utils@4.4.0
  node_modules/@eslint-community/eslint-utils
    @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.2.0" from eslint@8.41.0
  peer eslint@">= 3.2.1" from eslint-plugin-cypress@2.12.1
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-cypress
    dev eslint-plugin-cypress@"^2.11.3" from the root project
  peer eslint@"^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0 || ^8" from eslint-plugin-import@2.27.5
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
    peer eslint-plugin-import@"^2.22.1" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
    node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
      dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^14.2.1" from the root project
    dev eslint-plugin-import@"^2.23.4" from the root project
  dev eslint@"^8.41.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer eslint@"^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
  dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^14.2.1" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
node_modules/eslint
  peer eslint@"^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
  node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
    dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^14.2.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I am guessing that this error is telling me that I am getting dependency issues. These are chains of dependencies if I install/uninstall one then a second would arise.

So how can I resolve it?

Comment: If you check the code source of this packages, I would recommand to copy/past the code directly instead of having an another dependecy.

Comment: @Wandrille No one will approve my PR if copy pastes a huge code into my automation project :). I also think why should I manage someone else's code?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

- As it's suggested, force the installation with your configuration `npm i --force`
- Install all the dependencies (bigger node module) with `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`
- Get the source code and implement it manually.